# How to show dropdown list when hover pseudo class happens in blazorise?

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor, blazorise

I want to show the dropdownItem of menu bar when mouse is in dropdownToggle but I don't know which class should have changed.

```
    `<Bar Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Desktop"
 Background="Background.Light"
 ThemeContrast="ThemeContrast.Light"
 Class="sticky-top"
 Style="font-size:large; color:white">
<BarBrand>
    <CardImage Source="/photo/logoNew.jpg"></CardImage>
</BarBrand>
<BarToggler />
<BarMenu Class="navbar-dark">
    <BarStart>
        <BarItem>
            <BarLink To="/">home</BarLink>
        </BarItem>
        <BarItem>
            <BarDropdown>
                <BarDropdownToggle>aftersale services</BarDropdownToggle>
                <BarDropdownMenu>
                    <BarDropdownItem Clicked="@WarrantyPage">warranty</BarDropdownItem>
                    <BarDropdownItem Clicked="@AssistancePage">assistance</BarDropdownItem>
                    <BarDropdownItem Clicked="@SparePartsPage">spare parts</BarDropdownItem>
                    <BarDropdownItem Clicked="@DealersPage">dealers network</BarDropdownItem>
                </BarDropdownMenu>
            </BarDropdown>
        </BarItem>
</BarMenu>
</Bar>`
```